Fetching single image from Contentful
I am currently able to display all my images and titles on my products page of my react project.
Now I would like to create a single product page when I click on a item.
This is the function I am using to retrieve my data
const client = createClient({
    accessToken: 's4HlIPhRkQvXB2xEu8l28',
    space: 'zpu5y6hd',
})

const useFetchProducts = () => {
    const [product, setProduct] = useState([]);

    const getData = async () => {
        const res = await client.getEntries({ content_type: 'products' });
        const product = res.items.map((item) => {
            const { image, title } = item.fields;
            const id = item.sys.id;
            const img = image?.fields?.file?.url;
            return { img, title, id }
        });
        setProduct(product)
        //console.log(product)
    }
    useEffect(() => {
        getData()
    }, [])
    return { product }
}; 

This returns
0
: 
id
: 
"EEZDQsjqlxfJhKTlC622p"
img
: 
"//images.ctfassets.net/zpu537igy6hd/10jOjKpdTYAYRVc197KlAs/60910da04dceab7acda47c042261776e/397526804_263713576623932_2944288645324919698_n.jpg"
title
: 
"Winning Team"
[[Prototype]]
: 
Object
1
: 
id
: 
"30cJG3qFu7XBrwckoTmYMD"
img
: 
"//images.ctfassets.net/zpu537igy6hd/2fat5G5gnOIT00YAdoSVZg/ea3f8c44b62cf977bc8a0d5b3e4eeea7/397492507_267421149586508_6988846565487064728_n.jpg"
title
: 
"Elf on the Shelf"

How can I retrieve a single product rather than all of my products using client.getEntries, and get the image and title values?

To get a single entry you can use:
client.getEntry('<entry_id>')
.then((entry) =>  
        setProduct(entry);
        const { image, title } = entry.fields;
        const id = entry.sys.id;
        const img = entry?.fields?.file?.url;
        return { img, title, id }
 )
.catch(console.error)

Replacing <entry_id> with the id of the product in Contentful.
However for this to be useful you would have to know the entry_id of the product when calling UseFetchProducts(). So you would have to pass this into useFetchProduts(), getData or the component itself from the higher level component that is displaying all your products.

Thanks Folyik I followed your instructions and was able to retrieve title and id but not the image of a single entry.  const img = image?.fields?.file?.url; returns undefined. Code attached below if anyone can help

`const getData2 = async () => {
await client.getEntry('EEZDQsjqlxfJhKTlC622p').then((entry) => {
const { image, title } = entry.fields;
        const id = entry.sys.id;
        
        const img = entry?.fields?.file;
        setTitle(title)
        setImage(img)
        setId(id)
        console.log(title, id, img)

    })
}
getData2()`


Could you please include the returned JSON when querying a single entry?
But I think you might need to change it to const img = entry?.fields?.img;
Also does the image variable from const { image, title } = entry.fields; evaluate to a value?
